# How to load dynamically data from localStorage in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, local-storage

I'm trying to display data stored in localstorage dynamically, meaning when data is added to localstorage it should be also displayed on the same page at the same time. I have the following code:

```
const [peopleInfo, getPeopleInfo] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("peopleInfo"))
    );

    const [objects, getObjectsList] = useState(
        JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects"))
    );

    const setPeopleInfo = async () => {
        const people = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("peopleInfo"));
        getPeopleInfo(people);
    };

    const getObjects = async () => {
        const object = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects"));
        getObjectsList(object);
    };



    useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;

        if (isSubscribed) {
            setPeopleInfo();
            getObjects();
        }

                return () => (isSubscribed = false);

    });
```

When useEffect doesn't include getObject() like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
        let isSubscribed = true;

        if (isSubscribed) {
            setPeopleInfo();
        }

                return () => (isSubscribed = false);

    });
```

code works fine, peopleInfo gets updated every time when localStorage changes, but  when I include getObjects() and other similar functions to get all the necessary data, app crashes without showing errors. I don't know the reason why.  When I use useEffect with empty [], data doesn't get updated on localStorage change unless I refresh the page (this is not what I want). Can anyone please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 1):

According to your code useEffect call, every time when your state changes, if you are using [] as your dependency useEffect call only one time but I realize when you call getObjects() function in useEffect() it changes the state every time so your state changes infinity times

```
 import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
    import "./style.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [objects, getObjectsList] = useState([{ name: "object1" }]);
    
      useEffect(() => {
         getObjectsList([{ name: "object1" }])
        console.log("loop executed");
      });
      return <div />;
    }
```

so I just change some code

```
  import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
    import "./style.css";
    
        export default function App() {
          const [objects, getObjectsList] = useState([{ name: "object1" }]);
          useEffect(() => {
            setInterval(() => {
              const localStorageValue = [{ name: "object2" }]; //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("objects"));
              if (JSON.stringify(localStorageValue) !== JSON.stringify(objects)) {
                getObjectsList(localStorageValue);
              }
            }, [1000]);
          }, []);
        
          return <div />;
        }
```

in this code, setInterval check every time if your local storage changes it update your state

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo. I edited my code. In my app code is correct, state is being set with getObjectsList(), and async function is   getObjects().

Comment: if you check your useEffect call how many times I think your useEffect call every time when your state changes it's like an infinity loop

Comment: There's a [`storage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event) event to listen on. **Never use `setInterval` for polling a value when there's an event or callback for it!**

Comment: @FZs, storage event is not firing because data gets stored and retrieved on the same page. Could you please give an example of a callback in this situation?

Comment: In this case, you need to track all changes yourself. Create a function that wraps `localStorage.setItem()`, and call all functions stored in a global function array (or Set). Then, just add a custom function to that array in each component/anything that needs to be notified.